# VNC - simple test with vnc (x11vnc and ssvnc)

Tags: linux, vnc, x11vnc

I am trying to set up a vnc connection between 2 computers, but am having trouble so far.

In order to **understand the concept**, I am now simply trying to start a vnc server (using `x11vnc`) and connect to it using `ssvnc` **on the same computer**

[This page](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) supposedly explains how to do so.

Apparently, starting a vnc server should be as simple as downloading `x11vnc` and using the command `x11vnc -display :0`

The same page also contains a link to download `ssvnc`, that can be used as a vnc client ([link here for your convenience](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html#download))

It states that in order to connect using the vnc client, suffice to unpack the tar.gz directory, then run `./ssvnc/Unix/ssvnc`.

Then, I start ssvnc and type in user@localhost such as follow:

[image]

However when i press `connect`, a xterm windows appears, with the following message:

[image]

The x11vnc docs mentions that a common gotcha is to set the Xauth - I tried to do that by re-running the server with

```
x11vnc -display :0 -auth /home/user/.Xauthority
```

But I received the same error message.

Anyone can help me out here with that basic test / problem?

Answer (score 0):

x11vnc opens a VNC port at PORT=5900  (without encryption)
you do not need any options or parameters , just

```
x11vnc
```

will be enough for ONE connection.

ssvnc uses SSL by default.

- use "localhost" instead of "user@localhost"
- in ssvnc options use "None" instead of "use SSL"

alternative to ssvnc:

```
vncviewer localhost
```

Comment: Hi Thx! I will be able to test your solution tonight. Also If you want to apply to the upwork job, please do! It will entail helping me further to get the actual vnc connection (secured with ssh) between 2 PCs working though - but that should not be difficult for someone familiar with vnc.